# "Untokenize" a list of tokens

Tags: nlp

I am looking for a program, or library that can "untokenize" a list of tokens.

For example, given the list of tokens (each element of the list is separated by a space) `Forty-four patients ( 88 shoulders) completed the study .`, the output should be `Forty-four patients (88 shoulders) completed the study.`

Any operating system, price or license  is fine. I am mostly interested in the English language.

Comment: Apart from the couple of removed spaces the output seems to be identical to the input!

Comment: @SteveBarnes correct, the issue being which spaces to remove :-)

Comment: I feel like I would need to read your mind to understand what you're after here.  How about some input-output pair examples?

Comment: @aparente001 just use the typical English language rule regarding spacing and punctuation.

Comment: Are you saying that the input has some extraneous spaces inserted in strange places, and the output should have the extraneous spaces removed?  For the example you provided ("the study ."), my first thought would be to make a macro in MS Word that does a bunch of replacements.

Comment: @aparente001 that's correct: the input has some extraneous spaces inserted in strange places

Comment: What do you think of my MS Word macro idea?  I can walk you through it if you're interested but are not sure how to go about trying it.